# Bijection between two sets

Tags: combinatorics

The question is as follows:

For $m \geq k \geq 1$, find a bijection between $2$ sets.

A: subsets $\{a_1,\ldots,a_{2k}\}$ of $\{1,\ldots,2m\}$, such that $a_1 < \cdots < a_{2k}$, and $a_i$ has the same odd-even parity as i for all $i = 1,\ldots,2k$.

example: $m=3$, $k=2$, subsets can be $\{1,2,3,4\}$, $\{1,4,5,6\}$, $\{3,4,5,6\},\ldots$

B: $2k$-multiset with elements in $[m+k-1]$ = $\{(b_1,...,b_{2k})\mid 1\leq b_1\leq\cdots\leq b_{2k}\leq m-k+1\}$

Thanks!